# How do I insert rows in Mysql if row doesn't exist with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySql how do I insert a row if no row exists for a particular email, I need to create a thousand missing rows from a database table, I have a file of five thousand emails I dont know which of the email is already in the table and which is not.

I tried to construct an sql statement for each row like this but it is invalid sql syntax

```
insert into License (email) select unique 'person@gmail.com' where not exists (select 1 from License where email='person@gmail.com');
```

Email is not the primary key of the table and not neccessarily unique, all I am concerned about is if there is no record with the email address add a record otherwise do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by having a `from` clause for the `where`:

```
insert into License (email)
    select email
    from (select 'person@gmail.com' as email) t
    where not exists (select 1 from License l where l.email = t.email);
```

However, it makes more sense to do all the inserts in one statement:

```
insert into License (email)
    select t.email
    from database_table t
    where not exists (select 1 from License l where l.email = t.email);
```

You can add a `limit 1000`, if you only want 1000 of them.